# Django-registration & Django-Socialauth

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-apps

Have anyone used these 2 django apps together? I want to know how well these 2 gel together along with Django's User Authentication system.

When I mean Django's User Authentication System, I mean I should be able to use decorators like `@login_required` or grant permission to specific views (or functions in views.py) based on who the user is.

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but I use together django-registration and django-socialregistration (which I find superior to django-socialauth). There's no single problem with such combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn`t be any problems there. Django-Socialauth adda new auth backends, and it should works fine with permissions and decorators. And Django resistration just register a user on site, so unless you remove standard auth backend, it will work fine too.